# combining fields in two files

Tags: machine-learning, data-science-model

I'm a newbie when it comes to machine learning and I have the following problem:

I have two files that contain similar information and have the following structure:

A: 10, B: 5, C: 5, D: 9, E: 10, …
AA: 5, BB: 9, CC: 8, DD: 10, EE: 6, …

These files contain information such as name, surname, age, etc. All keys are to be combined to match each other. In both files, the keys may have different names. Most of those that correspond will contain similar values, and some will be slightly different.

I already have a quite large database in which the fields in two files are already combined correctly. How can I approach this?